# Append contents of a source file to a destination file

Tags: file, ansible

I need to scan `/etc/fstab` file for an entry and if it is not present append the contents of another file into `/etc/fstab`.

Ansible modules that I've seen do not seem to allow appending a file to another file instead just adding a specific "text" line.

Comment: Would the assemble module work? http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/assemble_module.html

Comment: assemble is more for concatenating a bunch of files in a directory into a single file. A typical example (and what it was written for) is for `conf.d` style directories into `.conf` files

Comment: Title does not match question.

Answer (score 10):

You can add or append content of a file to another file one of the following ways

```
-name: Add single line from a file
  lineinfile: path=destinationFile line={{lookup('file', 'sourceFile')}} create=yes state=present
-name: Add text block from a file
  blockinfile: path=destinationFile block={{lookup('file', 'sourceFile')}} create=yes state=present
```

The advantage of this - over previously mentioned solutions using command or shell modules - is in the fact that the source file does not need to be present on the remote machine.

Additionally, by  the nature of lineinfile or blockinfile functionality, the content of the sourceFile in destinationFile will not be added multiple times in multiple ansible executions.

See more about file lookup usage here:
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/plugins/lookup/file.html

Answer (score 9):

The [lineinfile](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/lineinfile_module.html) module could be used if your use case is simply checking that a specific line is present.

For example, if you want to make sure that there is a `/dev/sdb1` partition defined and that it is mapped to `/data` and using the ext4 filesystem then you could use:

```
lineinfile: dest=/etc/fstab regexp="^/dev/sdb1 " line="/dev/sdb1    /data    ext4    defaults    1  2"
```

If there's no line beginning with `/dev/sdb1` then it will add it to the end of the file. Helpfully, if the rest of the line doesn't match (for example if it's mounted as `ext3`) then it will change it to the provided line.

If you really need it to be using the entire contents of a file then you might be able to get away with using the [file lookup](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_lookups.html#id3) which might look something like:

```
lineinfile: dest=/etc/fstab regexp="^/dev/sdb1 " line="{{ lookup('file', 'files/fstabdata') }}"
```

I've not tested that though.

If your use case is around mounting disks then you might instead consider using the [mount](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/mount_module.html) module which will handle things even nicer.

If you're really stuck then you can always shell out with something like:

```
-name: Check for line in /etc/fstab
 command: grep /dev/sdb1
 changed_when: False
 register: shell_out

-name: Append to /etc/fstab
 command: cat /home/ansible/files/fstabdata >> /etc/fstab
 when: shell_out.std_out != ''
```

But in general with Ansible you should always look to use the modules provided before resorting to shelling out.

Comment: If the answer has helped you, you may want to consider [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). This has the benefit of showing future readers of the question with the same problem that this answer was beneficial for you. It also rewards you with 2 reputation score as an incentive!